# Ubuntu 14.04 won't boot even after Boot-Repair-Disk

Tags: system-installation

A fresh install of Ubuntu14.04 seems successful, but will not boot afterwards. 500Gb disk was formatted with Gparted to 499Gb ext4 with 1Mb unallocated prior to installation. Repairing with Boot-Repair-Disk seems not to work because upon next boot: "Disk Boot failure. Insert System Disk and press Enter.

Subsequently I have used Gparted to move and resize the ubuntu installation and create a 147Gb NTFS formatted blank partition. I still get the same "Disk Boot failure" as before.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7906804

Reccommended-repair from Boot-Repair-Disk does not change the boot failure

Comment: In bios is it set to still boot from CD?

Comment: Is this an older computer. Some will not boot from partitions that are beyond 137GB on drive. Your boot files are at 200 & 422 on drive. Then you may need either all of / (root) inside the first 100GB of drive or a separate /boot fully inside the first 100GB. You still can use rest of drive for /home or data partition(s).

Comment: Athlon XP Mobile (Unlocked) 2600+ running at 2266MHz
Yes, this computer is over 10 years old.1Gb Corsair Value Select memory 2X512 VS512MB400
Thermaltake Extreme Volcano 12 / Socket A (Socket 462) noisy
500Gb seagate ST3500312CS
Abit NF7-S nforce2 motherboard. I'll fiddle around with smaller partitions, although ubuntu 14.04 LTS works fine befor rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure it is trying to boot from the hard drive. Second, make sure that grub is actually installed to the mbr not just the partition you have ubuntu on. Third, you don't need a blank ntfs partition to be able to boot, and on machines that use bios you don't need an efi partition either

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't boot without the blank NTFS partition, with the full 500Gb hdd used as ubuntu's install. I would think that 14.04 would install grub itself.

Comment: it usually would, how did you install it?

Comment: From the 14.04 LTS install DVD, burned the .iso with imgburn. I'm going to redo everything with gparted and start over. Thanks again for your recommendations.

Comment: have you tried grub rescue disk to see if it boots at all with even that?